# adds only integers numbers of list

Tags: python, list

I tried lost of different commands but cant find how I can only count integers.

```
mix_list = [12, 3.3, -2, 'Flasche', 9, -4.1, 'Weg', 'auto', 2, 77, 0.5, 'X', 'Bla', 66.6, 22]
for i in mix_list:
    print(type(i),i)
```

Comment: Please show your effort and add the program(s) that you have made to the question.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a list comprehension to filter to only items which are integers, then counts that list items:

```py
mix_list = [12, 3.3, -2, 'Flasche', 9, -4.1, 'Weg', 'auto', 2, 77, 0.5, 'X', 'Bla', 66.6, 22, True]
total = len([x for x in mix_list if type(x) is int])
print(total)
```

Comment: I guess because of `isinstance(True, int)` is `True`, while `type(True) is int` is `False`?

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution if the following:

```
mix_list = [12, 3.3, -2, 'Flasche', 9, -4.1, 'Weg', 'auto', 2, 77, 0.5, 'X', 'Bla', 66.6, 22, True]

counts = len([x for x in mix_list if isinstance(x, int) and not isinstance(x, bool)])

print(counts)
```

Prints

```
6
```

Comment: as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71510206/adds-only-integers-numbers-of-list#comment126391409_71510256) this would fail if you have True/False that are instances of int but type bool ;)

Comment: @mozway `if isinstance(x, int) and not isinstance(x, bool)` should work as expected with boolean items

Comment: better use `type(x) is int` to have a single comparison, also you might have other unforeseen instances. But your approach might be correct, maybe OP wants to count booleans as integers! ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
mix_list = [12, 3.3, -2, 'Flasche', 9, -4.1, 'Weg', 'auto', 2, 77, 0.5, 'X', 'Bla', 66.6, 22]
m_int = []

for i in mix_list:
    if type(i) == int:
        m_int.append(i)
        print(i)

print(m_int)
```

The next option is faster, but the first one is more understandable.

```
m = [i for i in mix_list if type(i) == int]
print(m)
```

Comment: for type checking one would use `is` not `==`